# Facebook Messenger always crashing

Tags: crashes, facebook-messenger

I have a Dell Venue 8 tablet with Android 4.4.2. Today the Facebook Messenger application started to crash whenever I try to open it.

[image]

The crash doesn't happen in my phone (a Moto G running Android 4.4.4 and the same version of the FB messenger). From what I understand, libhoudini.so is the ARM emulation layer (this tablet is a x86 device).

No other apps (not even the main Facebook app) seem to present the problem.

I tried cleaning its cache/data and uninstalling/reinstalling it but didn't work. What else besides resetting the device can I try?

Comment: did you try a force stop and then the clear cache,restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well (almost 1 year later), apparently this doesn't happen anymore. I installed Messenger back a while ago and haven't had any crashes.